# Javascript/typescript promise returns two types?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, typescript

So, im running this code:

```
this.db.getDocumentClient()
      .then(client => client.query(params).promise())
      .then(data => { this.items = data.Items; })
      .catch(err => logger.debug('error in refresh tasks', err))
      .then(() => { this.refresher && this.refresher.complete() });
```

and getting this error:

```
 typescript: D:/Developer/scrum/myApp123/src/pages/tasks/tasks.ts, line: 51
        Property 'query' does not exist on type 'void | DocumentClient'. Property 'query' does not exist on type
        'void'.
```

What in the world is type 'void | DocumentClient'? getDocumentClient looks like this:

```
    getDocumentClient() {
    return Auth.currentCredentials()
      .then(credentials => new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ credentials: credentials }))
      .catch(err => logger.debug('error getting document client', err));
  }
```

Comment: Seems like there is no `query` method for client object (second row) or `getDocumentClient` failed and you got into `catch` promise block where you return nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise<void | DocumentClient>` is the return type of your `getDocumentClient()` function. The problem is that in `.catch` you do not re-throw the error and the function resolves to `Promise<void>`. To fix it, change your method to:

```
getDocumentClient() {
    return Auth.currentCredentials()
      .then(credentials => new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ credentials: credentials }))
      .catch(err => { logger.debug('error getting document client', err); throw err; });
  }
```

This will cause the promise in your main code to fail and enters to the catch part, instead of resolving to `void` and then getting the runtime error.